# vagrant ansible access other machines IP address

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vagrantfile, ansible-inventory

I have a vagrant file to create 3 VMs and an ansible to manage these 3 machines (inventory file is generated by the vagrant file). I need to access the VM no.1 IP address in order to put it in the configuration file of two other machines. but using `hostvars[vm1]` variable won't give me the IP address of the vm1.

Here is my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 512
  end
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  config.vm.define "vm1" do |vm1|
    vm1.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
  end

  config.vm.define "vm2" do |vm2|
    vm2.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
  end

  config.vm.define "vm3" do |vm3|
    vm3.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    #ansible.ask_become_pass = true
    ansible.groups = {
      "node_master" => ["vm1"],
      "node_replicas" => ["vm2", "vm3"],
      "node:children" => ["node_master", "node_replicas"]
    }
  end
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As configured, your ansible provisionner will run three times: once independently for each machine, being called with a limit set to the current machine name.

In this situation, the facts for all other machines will not be gathered in your playbook and `hostvars[vm1]` will be empty (unless you are currently running on vm1).

What you can try is to declare the provisionner on a single machine only (the best bet being vm3, the last one) and change the default current machine limit to `all`

```
config.vm.define "vm3" do |vm3|
    vm3.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

    vm3.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
      ansible.limit = "all"
      #ansible.ask_become_pass = true
      ansible.groups = {
        "node_master" => ["vm1"],
        "node_replicas" => ["vm2", "vm3"],
        "node:children" => ["node_master", "node_replicas"]
      }
    end
end
```

This way, your playbook will run on all your vms at once in parallel and you should be able to access facts from all the hosts you target in your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

I got no clue how to solve your specific version.

However, I use Vagrant and Ansible separately. Vagrant to only build the hosts with `vagrant up`, and Ansible to manage the configuration on those hosts.

I use this Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 1
  end

config.ssh.insert_key = false

config.vm.define "multi-1" do | localMulti1 |
  localMulti1.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  localMulti1.vm.hostname = "multi-1"
  localMulti1.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 30001, id: "ssh"
  localMulti1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.111"
         end

  config.vm.define "multi-2" do | localMulti2 |
    localMulti2.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    localMulti2.vm.hostname = "multi-2"
    localMulti2.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 30002, id: "ssh"
    localMulti2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.112"
  end

  config.vm.define "multi-3" do | localMulti3 |
    localMulti3.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    localMulti3.vm.hostname = "multi-3"
    localMulti3.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 30003, id: "ssh"
    localMulti3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.113"
    localMulti3.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
      ansible.inventory_path = "inventory"
      ansible.limit = "local_multi"
              end
           end
end
```

I place this in my inventory file:

```
[local_multi]
multi-1 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=30001 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
multi-2 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=30002 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
multi-3 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=30003 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Your playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: local_multi
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: check who is master
      debug: 
         msg: "{{ node_master }}"
      when: node_master is defined
```

Now you can place all your Ansible vars in the grouped or host vars;

```
./inventory
./playbook.yml
./Vagrantfile
./group_vars/all.yml
./host_vars/multi-1.yml
./host_vars/multi-2.yml
./host_vars/multi-3.yml
```